# Body Resize Called When Changing Tabs In Browser

Tags: javascript, html, window-resize

I am wanting to listen for window/browser resizing and i'm using the following piece of code:

```
var reloadTimer = null; 
document.body.onresize = function() {
    if(reloadTimer) clearTimeout(reloadTimer);
    reloadTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        //Perform complete page reload. Calls inits again.
        var page = pageData[core.getHash()];
        page.load(page.bindings);
    }, 400);        
};
```

Strange thing is, this gets fired when I change tabs in the browser. Not sure why changing the tabs would resize the body tag and thus fire the event. I am using Firefox and have not tested in other browsers so maybe its a FF bug, or is it a bug and am I just not doing something correctly?

**Update:**
Determined the cause of the problem is Firebug. Apparently it removes itself from the window when the tab changes, thus changing the height and firing the event. Anyone know how to disable this from happening in Firebug. It won't be a problem in production, but it quite annoying in dev mode.

Comment: Does it fire in the same instance if you try window.onresize = func..?

Comment: Yes, but see my update. I overlooked the fact that firebug was resizing the window on tab change.